# In node.js, I am making a POST request, before the response from the POST request is received, function is sending spaces to the endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the below code, response is sent to the endpoint before the post request execution is completed.

```
function(req, res) {
  var details;

  getPublisherDetails() {
    getPublisherDetailsFromServer();
  }

  res.send(details);

}

getPublisherDetailsFromServer() {
  var det;
  const JSON = require('circular-json');
  var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
  var client = new Client();

  var args = {
    data: {
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: "mk",
      client_secret: "Mank8"
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  };

  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  client.post(cache.getURL(), args, function(data, response) {
    console.log("Response from server-->" + JSON.stringify(data));
    det = data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
  });

  return det;
}
```

Above `det` does not contain anything unless the post request is completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how js async works. you need to send the response inside your `client.post` callback

```
function(req,res) {

  const JSON = require('circular-json');
  var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
  var client = new Client();
  var args = { 
   data:                                                                                      
   {grant_type:"client_credentials",client_id:"mk" 
       ,client_secret:"Mank8"},
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
   };

  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  client.post(cache.getURL(),args,function (data, response) {

    console.log("Response from server-->"+JSON.stringify(data));

    var det = data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
    res.send(det);

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. modified the calling the getPublisherDetails as below and sent the "det" from client.post.                                    
                                                                         
function(req,res){
        getPublisherDetailsFromServer(req,res);
 }